# Combining two tables into one using SELECT query, keeping records of both tables with different columns

Tags: sql

I try to combine two different tables into one using SELECT query. I tried with JOIN and with UNION, but both didn't result fully in what I want. See below the two source tables and what my result should look like.

Table 1:

```
case_id | email_id | subject
1         E1         subject_1
2         E2         subject_2
3         E3         subject_3
3         E4         subject_4
```

Table 2:

```
case_id | document_id | document_name
1         D1            document_1
1         D2            document_2
2         D3            document_3
3         D4            document_4
```

I want to have all documents and mails belonging to case 1

Result:

```
case_id | email_id | subject    | document_id | document_name
1         E1         subject_1    null          null
1         null       null         D1            document_1
1         null       null         D2            document_2
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Can you explain the logic? Why aren't E2, E3, E4, D3 and D4 in the result?

Comment: What's the logic behind this? Looks weird to me really

Comment: @Mureinik Only want the rows belonging to case 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to union two subqueries, using `NULL` values for the columns that are not relevant to the content of the table.

```
SELECT case_id, email_id, subject, null, null FROM table1 where case_id=1
UNION
SELECT case_id, null, null, document_id, document_name from table2 where case_id=1
```

The first query uses `NULL` for the `document_id` and `document_name` fields, while query #2 uses `NULL` for `email_id` and `subject`.

Comment: Side note: `UNION ALL` is (far) more efficient than `UNION`, and should be used here instead of `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

A full outer join that never matches any rows:

```
select coalesce(t1.case_id, t2.case_id), ...
from t1 full outer join t2 on 0 = 1
where t1.case_id = 1 or t2.case_id = 1;
```